# Microsoft ClickOnce Deployment Question

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

I want to deploy an application using ClickOnce Technology. The application depends on .xml file. The location of the .xml file is provided in the App.config file. This .xml file can be changed by the user. With ClickOnce, i only see (.appref-ms) file downloaded. Is it possible to download dependent files that can be modified by users?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First, be sure you're looking in the right place for the files.  Applicaitons deployed via ClickOnce are not stored where you'd expect if you haven't run across this before.  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k390a.aspx

Second, you can include additional files (termed here as local data).  See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy.aspx

**Added**  This might be more helful than the link above.  It's a how-to that covers choosing which files are installed.  It more directly answers your question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you add an XML to a ClickOnce project to be deployed, please note that C/O will assume that it's data, and deploy it to ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory. If you look in ApplicationFiles, you can change it from Include(Data) to Include(Required), and it will put it in the same location as the exe file. From there, you can copy it to wherever you want to, assuming that you have permissions to write to that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can always stored the file as a resouce and get your app to write out a file the first time it starts up.